# Numpy/Pandas: Merge two numpy arrays based on one array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two numpy arrays comprised of two-set tuples:

```
a = [(1, "alpha"), (2, 3), ...]
b = [(1, "zylo"), (1, "xen"), (2, "potato", ...]
```

The **first element in the tuple is the identifier and shared between both arrays**, so I want to create a new numpy array which looks like this:

```
[(1, "alpha", "zylo", "xen"), (2, 3, "potato"), etc...]
```

My current solution works, but it's way too inefficient for me. Looks like this:

```
aggregate_collection = []
for tuple_set in a:
  for tuple_set2 in b:
    if tuple_set[0] == tuple_set2[0] and other_condition:
      temp_tup = (tuple_set[0], other tuple values)
      aggregate_collection.append(temp_tup)
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: I suspect the `pandas.group_by` answers just hide the complexity.  Are you sure these are numpy arrays?  They look more like lists of tuples.  This isn't the kind of task that benefits from `numpy`

Comment: @hpaulj These are numpy arrays with a singular tuple element.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't look like `pandas` is the right approach. Doesn't look like `numpy` is the correct data structure for this either, since you have multiple types mixed together. I think this [mcve] is does not represent the actual problem :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [278]: a = [(1, "alpha"), (2, 3)]
     ...: b = [(1, "zylo"), (1, "xen"), (2, "potato")]
In [279]: a
Out[279]: [(1, 'alpha'), (2, 3)]
In [280]: b
Out[280]: [(1, 'zylo'), (1, 'xen'), (2, 'potato')]
```

Note that if I try to make an array from `a` I get something quite different.

```
In [281]: np.array(a)
Out[281]: 
array([['1', 'alpha'],
       ['2', '3']], dtype='<U21')
In [282]: _.shape
Out[282]: (2, 2)
```

`defaultdict` is a handy tool for collecting like-keyed values

```
In [283]: from collections import defaultdict
In [284]: dd = defaultdict(list)
In [285]: for tup in a+b:
     ...:     k,v = tup
     ...:     dd[k].append(v)
     ...: 
In [286]: dd
Out[286]: defaultdict(list, {1: ['alpha', 'zylo', 'xen'], 2: [3, 'potato']})
```

which can be cast as a list of tuples with:

```
In [288]: [(k,*v) for k,v in dd.items()]
Out[288]: [(1, 'alpha', 'zylo', 'xen'), (2, 3, 'potato')]
```

I'm using `a+b` to join the lists, since it apparently doesn't matter where the tuples occur.

`Out[288]` is even a poor `numpy` fit, since the tuples differ in size, and items (other than the first) might be strings or numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd concatenate these into a data frame and just `groupby`+`agg`

```
(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a), pd.DataFrame(b)])
   .groupby(0)
   .agg(lambda s: [s.name, *s])[1])
```

where `0` and `1` are the default column names given by creating a dataframe via `pd.DataFrame`. Change it to your column names.

Comment: Can you explain the `agg(lambda s: [s.name, *s])[1]` in more depth? This also does not meet the conditional that I wrote within the double nested for loop.

Comment: `agg` aggregates all values into a single list. `[s.name, *s]` means that this list will have the fist item as the index (in your example, 1 and 2) and the rest of the items whatever is in the lists (in your example, `"alpha", "zylo", "xen"` for index 1 and ` 3, "potato"` for index 2). The other conditions would go into the groupby as well, but I don't know them and is hard to predict how the structure would look like.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm comparing two sets of time and making sure they fall within an interval i.e. `a_time - b_time <= time_delta_interval`. Would that fit fine into the `group_by`?